# Filtro angular para pasaar cadena HTML

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, angular

Hola como puedo hacer un filtro de `angular`, para que lea una cadena `html` ,o como creo un método para que lea una cadena`html`

```
<div ng-bind-html="item.description"></div>
```

por que cuando le guardo texto con [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me lo guarda pero me muestra las etiquetas html 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<div class="des-img_gal-pre" ng-show="item.have_description">
      <div ng-bind-html="item.description"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar la directiva [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "Mi nombre es: <h1>Carlos :)</h1>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>

</div>
```

> **Nota:** Este ejemplo incluye el "*angular-sanitize.js*", que tiene
>   funciones para eliminar tokens potencialmente peligrosos del HTML

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte , pero mira que en el formulario que muestro la información ya puse la etiqueta ng-bind-html , lo cual no se por que pueda fallar esta etiqueta